# My Expo App Throws JavascriptException when download from Google Play Store

Tags: react-native, google-play, expo

When I test the app with apk on my android phone it works fine but when I build .aab and submit it to Play Store and download it, It crashes after splash screen. I'm trying to fix this for days but can't find any similar issue around here. Here is crash log Google Play gave me. Thanks !

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Requiring module "582", which threw an exception: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'l.default.createNode'), stack:
h@2:1476
<unknown>@1379:1054
h@2:1585
<unknown>@1378:183
h@2:1585
<unknown>@1377:139
h@2:1585
<unknown>@1349:654
h@2:1585
<unknown>@1348:139
h@2:1585
<unknown>@1103:239
h@2:1585
<unknown>@1101:173
h@2:1585
<unknown>@730:171
h@2:1585
<unknown>@723:148
h@2:1585
<unknown>@469:854
h@2:1585
<unknown>@6:57
h@2:1585
d@2:958
global code@1613:3
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run (Native Method)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:224)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: Hello Bora, please share the solution if you have fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Hello sorry for late answer. I guess React 18 cause the problem. I downgraded React version to 17.x and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello sorry for late answer. I guess React 18 cause the problem. I downgraded React version to 17.0.1 and it worked :)